# "When the next semester commence..." or "When the next semester commences..."?

Tags: grammar, verbs, british-english, prepositional-phrases

Which is correct? :"When the next semester **commence**..." or "When the next semester **commences**...".

Comment: Semester isn't a term that's commonly used in British English are you sure you meant to tag it that way?

Comment: The English law of the preservation of "s".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When the next semester commences...". = agreement

"When the next semesters commence...". = agreement

"When the next semester commence...". = disagreement